# spdlog error: "don't know how to format the type, include fmt/ostream.h if it provides an operator<< that should be used"

Tags: c++, spdlog, fmt

I've just picked up spdlog in an effort to improve our logging.  Our logging is very basic, so I'm just copying the "multi sink" example  almost verbatim to log to file and console.

However, even when following the example exactly, I get:

Error   C2338   don't know how to format the type, include fmt/ostream.h if it provides an operator<< that should be used   Logger  d:\tfs\development\bladed\main\external\spdlog\spdlog-1.x\include\spdlog\fmt\bundled\core.h 351

Coming from core.h:

```
// A formatter for objects of type T.
template <typename T, typename Char = char, typename Enable = void>
struct formatter {
  static_assert(no_formatter_error<T>::value,
    "don't know how to format the type, include fmt/ostream.h if it provides "
    "an operator<< that should be used");
```

I'm presuming this is really easy to fix, but I can't see it...

[basic Win32 usage]

Comment: You might want to add a [mcve]

Comment: Also, you might want to specify your environment, like the version of your compiler, OS, etc.

Comment: Did you try `include fmt/ostream.h` like the error suggests?

Comment: I tried adding #include "ostream" (it did nothing), #include "spdlog\fmt\ostr.h" (also did nothing), but "fmt/ostream.h" and "spdlog\fmt\ostr.h" do not exist.

Comment: Correction: Intellisense has decided that #include "spdlog\fmt\ostr.h" *does* exist after all, but it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @MikeSadler What type are you trying to format?  Wild guess -- are you using `std::string` or similar, and forgot to `#include <string>` in your source?

Comment: I'm also never using the << operator, as the error appears to think (this is to do with custom loggers, if I understand the user guide).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - I am using string, but it is coming in via the header file.

Comment: If this is Visual C++, I know that not including `<string>` and using the streaming operators on `std::string` will cause similar compiler errors.  If you're not explicitly including `<string>`, you need to include it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - it wasn't std::string, but I was attempting to log std::wstrings - they were included, and intellisense was happy with them, but it seems that spdlog couldn't swallow them after all.  Basically, I was logging an unknown type.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie if you want to phrase that as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it as such...

Comment: @MikeSadler -- So the solution was to specify `#include <string>`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie no, I think that if you want to use wstrings, you have to write a custom handler for it.  I was given a false sense of security, because Intellisense seems perfectly happy with sending it wstrings (I presume it's a side effect of the templating).

Comment: ok.  I think you should write up the solution, since I only gave hints and you know the library better than I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With @PaulMcKenzie pointing me in the right direction, it seems that I was trying to log a type of string that spdlog cannot handle by default (std::wstrings).

Visual Studio's Intellisense seemed to be confused by the templating, making it appear to be happy with my sending spdlog::warn a std::wstring.

Solution: either just use std::string, or if you want to use wstrings you (probably) need to define a custome formatter for them.

Comment: You can define SPDLOG_WCHAR_TO_UTF8_SUPPORT before including spdlog.h to format wstrings like this: logger->info(L”some wstring param: {}”, wstr);